# Correct way to call a GET request when navigating to a new screen in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, get

I have a screen that needs to asynchronously call a GET request from an API, display an activity indicator while the request is not done, then display the results in the screen if the request is successful. The request must be done the moment the user navigates to the screen though.

I'm using MVVM and I set the Binding Context on the code behind of the screen.

```
public DashboardView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new DashboardViewModel(Navigation);
        BindingContext = viewModel;

        viewModel.GetUserProfile(); // This is the GET request            
    }
```

This works fine, however, I know this is already wrong and will cause complications later. From what I've read, you shouldn't call any async operations in the constructor.

Where should I call the GET request in the View Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use `Task`. As constructor has no return type `async` call can cause issue. This will trigger your next page once after completing your call.

```
Task.Run(() => viewModel.GetUserProfile()).Wait();
```